# Why is the rough ER necessary to make extracellular proteins?

Tags: eukaryotic-cells, organelle

It is my current understanding that free ribosomes synthesise proteins to be used inside the cell, and the rough endoplasmic reticulum is necessary to make proteins that are to be secreted by the cell. Is this correct - and more importantly, if so, why?

Comment: Please do some research before posting questions and demonstrate that you have done so in your question. This is basic material that can be found online and in standard biochemistry textbooks.

Comment: While the default textbook will likely cover co-translational transfer of nascent proteins into the ER (which topologically corresponds to the outside of cells), there are also other mechanisms that apply to some proteins and don't necessitate rough ER ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exosome_(vesicle) )

Comment: Ahhh I did search for a while and found nothing (in terminology could comprehend anyway) and don't own a biochemistry textbook as I am not doing a biochemistry course

Comment: Cell Biology books also cover this. You need to buy books if you are studying. Sacrifice other things, but buy books. However you could have answered this question on the web using [NCBI Bookshelf](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/), which has older editions of some excellent texts, including Berg et al. Biochemistry, Alberts et al. Molecular Biology of the Cell, and Lodish et al. Molecular Cell Biology.  Searching for Endoplasmic Reticulum brings up a list, which includes these three books, which you can then consult. Learn to save your own life.

Comment: I did research the question online beforehand - however perhaps the wording of my question brought up other results? I could find nothing that would help me when I searched. In the future, I will use that website as I've used it a couple of times (when it came up after a search) and it was very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracellular proteins are proteins that function outside the cell, meaning they are made in cells (transcribed from ribosomes) and then are transported to the plasma membrane to be delivered to the extracellular space. The proteins that need to be secreted aren't secreted as free proteins, rather they are packaged into vesicles. Vesicles are membrane-enclosed structures. When ribosomes are translating mRNA and come across a specific sequence called a [signal peptide (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_peptide), the ribosome goes to the ER and delivers the peptide into the ER. From here, the peptide gets packaged into a vesicle-- first a membrane budding off from the ER. 
[image] [source(NCBI)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21471/)

This is also how secretory proteins get into the Golgi, by vesicle trafficking. From the golgi, proteins are packaged into vesicles. It is a hotly debated topic whether proteins are sorted into specific vesicles or proteins within vesicles (that do not belong in that vesicle) are sorted away (and degraded by the lysosome).